# Not getting refreshed data from DE in Dynamic Content Block

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder, contactbuilder

I am using dynamic content block in an email to display the block as per the rule. The rule says that if the value of a particular column in my source DE is false, then the block should be displayed.

I am using this email in a journey which runs on that same DE(as mentioned above) that contains a column 'purchased' of type Boolean. Value of this field is set to false by default. Once the contact purchases the item, the data in this DE is updated via API call to true. After a wait of 5 days, this email is triggered to contact. If by that time if the value of this column in DE is changed to true, then that particular block shouldn't be displayed in the email.

But looks like that the dynamic content block is not taking the refreshed value from DE. It is still taking the old value i.e., false and displaying the block.

I tried this with ampscript and it's working fine. But I don't prefer to use ampscript in this case as it is a much more complex scenario, I have just taken an example to explain my case.

Any help with this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are basing your decision logic on the Journey Entry data, then think of this as a snap-shot of data which remains the same as&when your record enters the journey. The same value of the journey entry passes along the journey and even if you update the value in the Data Entry source it wouldn't update the value at a later point in time of your journey.

If you want to reflect the content on an updated value of the contact record, then you need to make the decision long on the Contact Data or alternatively use AMPscript to lookup the records from a nominated data extension.

Think of making decisions of the Contact Data as looking up the most up-to-date value, and the Journey Entry data as the 'snap shot' in time as to when they entered the journey.

Comment: No, I am taking the entry source as contact data only.  Journey data remains same and that will not work in my case where I need refreshed data.
Also, I am facing issue with the **dynamic content** in my email and not with journey's entry source. 
As mentioned in the question, I was preferring not to use Ampscript as mine is a bit complex case and I would end up using multiple ifs and elses that might make the code messy but I would use Ampscript if I don't get a better solution. @iManage